# Prove that $T$ is a linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(v_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ ∈ $l^2$ be a fixed sequence of real numbers.
Define a mapping T on $X=l^\infty$ using the formula
$T(a_1,a_2,...) = (v_1a_1,v_2a_2,...),$    $x=(a_1,a_2,...)∈ l^\infty$.

I have already proved that $Tx ∈ l^2$ for every $x∈l^\infty$ for the first part of this question, the next part asks me to prove that
$$T:(l^\infty, ||⋅||_\infty)\rightarrow (l^2,||⋅||_2)$$
is a linear operator.

Comment: Is your question on the next part? What is your question? Also if that is your question, what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. My question is the next part, verifying that T is a linear operator, the notes I have aren't clear but I've tried to do this using the definition but it's not really working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The operator $T$ is linear if the following hold for $s,t\in l^\infty$,  $c\in\mathbb{R}$:

1) $\quad$ $T(s+t) = T(s) + T(t)$

2) $\quad$ $T(c\cdot s) = c\cdot T(s)$

So

$T(s+t) = (v_1(s_1+t_1),v_2(s_1+t_1),...)$ by definition of the operator, can you gontinue from here?

Comment: Oh right, so do I only really need to show that the conditions of linearity are met?

Comment: Yes, that is right.